# Why I can't import a GitHub module to Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, github

I want to use this package in Xcode [Sliders](https://github.com/kieranb662/Sliders-SwiftUI)

When I try to import it using File -> Swift Packages -> Add Package Dependency it gives an error that a required GitHub package doesn't exist anymore([Shapes](https://github.com/kieranb662/Shapes.git)). The problem was that the repository changed its name to SwiftUI-Shapes.

The only solution was to download the "Sliders" package locally and change the link from the Package.swift file to the new "Shapes" repository.

I did that, I dragged the package folder to my Xcode project and when I try to import the module it doesn't work.

`No such module 'Sliders'`

Is there a different way to use a GitHub package in Xcode? Is it not possible to use a package locally, without import it from GitHub?

Comment: Why not fork the repo, change it there, and then add the package with the link like normal?

Comment: I did that now, I changed the link to the new one and it's still not working.

Comment: @VladPoncea are you trying to import by url of your forked repository, or the original one?

Comment: I tried to import by url from my forked repository, where I changed the link to the new one, and it's still not working. Here is the error. ```https://github.com/kieranb662/Shapes.git: The remote repository could not be accessed. Make sure a valid repository exists at the specified location and that the correct credentials have been supplied.```